# Laravel Validation - number of elements in an array

Tags: laravel

Looking at the language file that is defined in laravel for validation, it looks like between, min, max, and size have qualifiers of 'numeric', 'file', 'string', 'array'. How would I specify one of these sub-qualifiers in my validation? I don't see any documentation on how to declare 'no more than X elements in an array'. All I fine are things like 'max:10'.

How would I specify 'no more than X elements in an array' as a validation rule?

Comment: The docs mention file, string, and array for those validations, but fail to mention array.  I'm assuming you don't have to do anything to specify sub-qualifier as it should happen automatically.  Have you tried it just using size?

Comment: file, string, and numerics*

Comment: I solved this issue by adding my own validation rule. It is very easy, check [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).